# basic integer swap with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, integer, swap

Im trying to swap a few integers using pointers and for some reason im not fully understanding whats happening.

```
cout<< "x: " << x <<endl;
cout<< "y: " << y <<endl;

temp = *p2;
*p2 = *p1;
*p1 = temp; 

cout<< "x: " << x <<endl;
cout<< "y: " << y <<endl;
```

The output im getting is:
x: 0
y: 99
x: 0
y: 0

Thanks

Edit: Thats what i believe is the problematic area. The code in its entirety is a series of pointer tasks.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void swap(int *x, int *y);
void noNegatives(int *x);
int main ()
{
int x,y,temp;
int *p1, *p2;

p1 = &x;
*p1 = 99;

cout << "x: " << x << endl;
cout << "p1: " << *p1 << endl;

p1 = &y;
*p1 = -300;

p2 = &x;
temp = *p1;  
*p1 = *p2;
*p2 = temp;

noNegatives(&x);
noNegatives(&y);

p2=&x;
cout<< "x: "<<*p2<<endl;
p2=&y;
cout<< "y: "<<*p2<<endl;

int a[1];  
p2 = &a[0];
*p2 = x;
cout << "First Element: " << p2<< endl;

p2 = &a[1];
*p2 = y;
cout << "Second Element: " << p2<< endl;

p1 = &a[0];
p2 = &a[1];

cout<< "x: " << x <<endl;
cout<< "y: " << y <<endl;

temp = *p2;
*p2 = *p1;
*p1 = temp;

cout<< "x: " << x <<endl;
cout<< "y: " << y <<endl;

cout << "First Element: " << a[0]<< endl;
cout << "Second Element: " << a[1]<< endl;

swap(&x,&y);
cout<< "x: " << x <<endl;
cout<< "y: " << y <<endl;


swap(&a[0], &a[1]);
cout<< "a[0]: " << a[0] <<endl;
cout<< "a[1]: " << a[1] <<endl;
}

void noNegatives(int *x)
{
    if(*x<0)
            *x=0;

}

void swap(int *p1, int *p2)
{
    int temp;

    temp = *p1;
    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 = temp;
}
```

my goal is for the last x and y to be x: 99 and y: 0.
Everything else works as it should.

oh my god nevermind it was the array. Thank you so much for catching that bonehead error.

Comment: How are the three variables initialized?

Comment: can you post full code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty bad news:

```
int a[1];
```

You want 2 elements, not 1.  As you have defined it currently, reading or writing at `a[1]` is past the end of the array, and will have undefined behaviour.

Do this:

```
int a[2];

// etc...

p1 = &a[0];
p2 = &a[1];
```

Comment: a[0] and a[1] wont suffice? wait oh my god i just realized what i wrote

Comment: @user2272467 if this answer helped u, plz click the check mark besides it to mark the question as answered

Comment: YES, I was obsessing over the swap so much i never noticed that little miscalculation. THANK YOU

Answer (score 2):

assuming `p1` and `p2` point to `x` and `y` u can visualize it thus

u have ur three vars

```
           temp [ ]

    *p1 [ x ]        *p2 [ y ]
```

and we want to switch `*p1` and `*p2` first we do

```
temp = *p2

           temp [ y ]
                  ^
                  |________
                            \
    *p1 [ x ]          *p2 [ y ]
```

then

```
*p2 = *p1

               temp [ y ]

     *p1 [ x ] ----------> *p2 [ x ]
```

then

```
*p1 = temp

               temp [ y ]
                     /
          /----------
          V
    *p1 [ y ]                  *p2 [ x ]
```

and now u see that `*p1` and `*p2` are switched.

Comment: This is a very nice illustration, but it doesn't explain why the OP's code doesn't work.

Comment: @mbratch the question b4 he edited it was how swap worked, i answered that